# css 3d cubes - hover and rendering errors

Tags: css

I'm trying to create 3 3d cubes with the same perspective which will rotate 90 deg on hover.
It almost works on chrome, but if you look closely on the left cube's bottom border, you can see 1 blue px line.
There is also error on ff when you mouse over right box. 
How can i remove it?

I tried to add  `backface-visibility: hidden`, `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`

The second problem is that when you move over cube, it acts like you are leaving cube area.

Here is what i've made so far:
http://codepen.io/pioncz/pen/jEVJWo

Answer (score 1):

I think this rendering issue might be caused by perspective. After change it works fine for me:
[image]

Comment: With image it's hard to see this effect, but there is.

Comment: Maybe try to remove top/bottom faces when they are not necessary? I am still pretty sure it is webkit rendering issue.